# Return terminates for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to define a following function that should return all odd numbers between two given numbers, however the return terminates the for loop such that only the first number is returned. How do I overcome this?

```
def oddNumbers(l,r):
L=[]
for i in range (l,r+1):
    L.append(i)
for i in range (len(L)):
    if L[i] % 2 !=0:
        return(L[i])
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting with Python, I recommend you to read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in order to know more about the style guide for Python in general. Hope you enjoy your Python journey!

Regarding your function, as you mentioned, Python terminates the execution of a program when a `return` is found. It's not a basic concept, but Python has something called `generators` (you can check more [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)) that you can use to easy fix your function:

```py
def odd_numbers(l, r):
    for i in range (l, r + 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue
        else:
            yield i
```

See that I simplified the function a bit (just one `for` loop is necessary). The most important part is the change from `return` to `yield`. That's the part where you create a generator. It's basically a "lazy" (memory efficient) return that doesn't terminate the execution.

Answer (score 0):

if `generators` is too difficult for you, you can try this.

code:

```
def odd_numbers(l,r):
    ans = []
    for i in range (l,r+1):
        if i % 2 == 1:
            ans.append(i)
    return ans

print(odd_numbers(1,10))
```

result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

A more pythonic to do it by using `list comprehension`

code:

```
def odd_numbers_list_comprehension(l,r):
    return [i for i in range (l,r+1) if i % 2 == 1]

print(odd_numbers_list_comprehension(1,10))
```

result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```